# Add dynamically created string to an array

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I am making an iphone app in which I want to store the dynamically selected time into an array, but unable to implement the method to store the strings into an array. Following is the code which I am using but it is not giving the output.

```
- (void)storetimeintoanarray:(id)sender
{
    NSDateFormatter *df3 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df3 setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];
    timestr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[df3 stringFromDate:objtimepicker.date]];
    NSLog(@"time is:%@",timestr);
    test = [[NSArray alloc]init];
    [test arrayByAddingObject:timestr];
    NSLog(@"array time:%@",test);
}
```

Comment: Such a basic question could have been answered by searching.

Comment: Bit of a side comment, make sure you release the dateformatter at the end of your function.

Answer (score 1):

After allocating you shouldn't allocate the array again. `arrayByAddingObject` returns a auto released new array. Also use a `NSMutableArray` when you want to add objects dynamically.
Change the code to

```
test = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[test addObject:timestr];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare array mutable object.

```
test = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[test addObject:timestr];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `NSMutableArray` if you want to change it after creation.

```
NSMutableArray* arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[arr addObject:timestr];
```

To create an array with a single object, you can use:

```
NSArray* arr = [NSArray arrayWithObject:timestr];
```

Comment: It is adding one string at a time, but I want to add number of strings into the array.

Comment: hey Akshay, if you can answer me my question by doing simple searching, then give me the exact answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign the result of the `arrayByAddingObject:` method to a new array like:

```
NSArray *newone = [test arrayByAddingObject:timestr];
```

Comment: No, _arrayByAddingObject_ is not a class method it works on the receiver and returns an NSArray. Look at [Apple Dev](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/arrayByAddingObject:)

Comment: Ok my Bad, i just assumed is a class method. Sorry about that. Thanks for the link though. And yeah +1 since your answer is also very relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `NSMutableArray` and its method `addObject:` instead of NSArray. `[test arrayByAddingObject:timestr];` does nothing with your array test, its create new array

Comment: What aknew meant is that what you are doing doesnt add anything to the test array it creates a new one from it which you must create yourself aswell and you are logging the contents of an empty array. Either do it like Matthias has or use addObject: as the others have suggested.